# Django http response code 500 error

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to order a bunch of coordinates by their distance to another input coordinate. Whenever I try to order, I get the error code 500. Any ideas?

Here's an image of the response codes and I circled the error code associated with my GET request.

[image]

Here's the Javascript in the Django template:

```
function searchWaypoints() {
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': $('#address').val()
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var position = results[0].geometry.location;
            $.get("{% url 'waypoints-search' %}", {
                lat: position.lat(),
                lng: position.lng()
            }, function (data) {
                if (data.isOk) {
                    $('#waypoints').html(data.content);
                    waypointByID = data.waypointByID;
                    activateWaypoints();
                } else {
                    alert(data.message);
                }
            }, 'json');
        } else {
            alert('Could not find geocoordinates for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
$('#searchWaypoints').click(searchWaypoints);
$('#address').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) searchWaypoints();
});
```

Here's the urls.py"

```
urlpatterns = patterns('waypoints.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index', name='waypoints-index'),
    url(r'^save$', 'save', name='waypoints-save'),
    url(r'^search$', 'search', name='waypoints-search'),
)
```

Here's the view in views.py:

```
def search(request):
    'Search waypoints'
    # Build searchPoint
    try:
        searchPoint = Point(float(request.GET.get('lng')), float(request.GET.get('lat')))
    except:
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(dict(isOk=0, message='Could not parse search point')))
    # Search database
    waypoints = Waypoint.objects.distance(searchPoint).order_by('distance')
    # Return
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(dict(
        isOk=1,
        content=render_to_string('waypoints/waypoints.html', {
            'waypoints': waypoints
        }),
        waypointByID=dict((x.id, {
            'name': x.name,
            'lat': x.geometry.y,
            'lng': x.geometry.x,
        }) for x in waypoints),
    )), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: {% url 'waypoints-search' %} this might not render correctly, could you post your errors from your javascript console.?

Comment: Also, why are you returning html in the json?

Comment: I named the view 'waypoints-search' in the urls.py so I don't think there should be any problems. I opened Firefox debugger and I don't see any error logs for some reason. Any ideas?

I thought the html is made into a string and then returned in the json.

Comment: is your dubug flag is true? Could you open your settings and look for debug. Where is that json call is happening?

Comment: install firebug and turn it on, then look for any errors and post it here.

Comment: TypeError at /search
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/search?lat=41.8781136&lng=-87.62979819999998

Comment: Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Michael\PycharmProjects\googlemaps\waypoints\views.py" in search
  60.     )), mimetype='application/json')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py" in __init__
  318.         super(HttpResponse, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /search
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `mimetype='application/json'` to `content_type="application/json"`

or you can just use JsonResponse in Django

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Comment: You read my mind. I did a Google search and found the answer :D

Comment: I got a new tool under my belt thanks to you. Firebug! Thank you.